# How do I get the dynamic number of columns back?

Tags: sql, postgresql

There are three tables that store information about different types of users in the **PostgreSQL** database. For example, a table for internal users, a table for company clients, or a table for unidentified users. As you can see the number and names of columns in tables are different. I have a list of user IDs. I need to check them in the `users` table. Is it possible to return a different selection depending on the type of user? For example, if after checking the table `users` it turned out that the user is internal, then I want to return data from the `internal_users` table. Now I have to use CASE statement to check each column and this is not very efficient. I thought of combining all three tables into a single table, but the number of columns will increase over time.

This is the table for **internal users** of the project:

```
create table internal_users (
    internal_user_id uuid not null default uuid_generate_v4() primary key,
    internal_user_first_name varchar not null,
    internal_user_last_name varchar not null,
    internal_user_middle_name varchar null,
    internal_user_primary_email email not null unique,
    internal_user_secondary_email email null unique,
    internal_user_primary_phone_number varchar not null unique,
    internal_user_secondary_phone_number varchar null unique,
    internal_user_profile_photo_url text null,
    internal_user_password text not null
);
```

This is the table for **company clients** of the project:

```
create table company_clients (
    company_client_user_id uuid not null default uuid_generate_v4() primary key,
    company_client_first_name varchar null,
    company_client_last_name varchar null,
    company_client_middle_name varchar null,
    company_client_primary_email email null unique,
    company_client_secondary_email email null unique,
    company_client_primary_phone_number varchar null unique,
    company_client_secondary_phone_number varchar null unique,
    company_client_profile_photo_url text null,
    gender varchar not null,
    city varchar null,
    country varchar null,
    metadata json not null
);
```

This is the table for **unidentified users** of the project:

```
create table unidentified_users (
    unidentified_user_id uuid not null default uuid_generate_v4() primary key,
    metadata json not null
);
```

The global table that stores information about what type of user the user belongs to:

```
create table users (
    user_id uuid not null default uuid_generate_v4() primary key,
    internal_user_id uuid null,
    foreign key (internal_user_id) references internal_users (internal_user_id),
    company_client_id uuid null,
    foreign key (company_client_id) references company_clients (company_client_id),
    unidentified_user_id uuid null,
    foreign key (unidentified_user_id) references unidentified_users (unidentified_user_id)
);
```

Comment: is it possible to have same user in different table?

Comment: No, that's not possible. Logically, a single user cannot be in multiple tables at the same time. However, unidentified users may eventually end up in the `company_clients` table. In theory, you can only combine the `company_clients` and `unidentified_users` tables. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: It might be faster to aquire all data using left joins and then handle the cases in code